# Explaining Two Long Employment Gaps When I was a Recent Grad?

Tags: resume, job-search, employment-gaps

I graduated from pharmacy school in May 2012 and had a difficult time finding a position. I had several interviews but in the end, I did not end up with a job. It wasn't until I was contacted by a recruiter in October that I had employment. However, it was only a temporary assignment that only lasted from November to February of 2013. And that began a second employment gap.

But since October 2013, I've been working at the same company (albeit a lot of it as a temporary worker), with the exception of May 2014, when I was between contract assignments with the same company. But since October of last year, I've been an actual employee with my current company.

The thing I did during that time period was complete the application to go back to school and complete a master's degree related to healthcare, but I did not actually start classes until Fall of 2013.

So I have a two gaps in my work history, one of ~6 months and another of ~8 months. And my job history has been completely with the same company.

- November 2012 to February 2013 (Company X via Agency 1)
- October 2013 to April 2014 (Company X via Agency 2)
- June 2014 to September 2014 (Company X via Agency 2)
- October 2014 to Present (Company X)

I completed my Master's recently and am exploring career options combining my two degrees, even with my current employer.

Comment: Everything looks fine, just tell them what you told us. Perhaps in your resume you can include a line to explain the employment gap.

Answer (score 1):

Gaps can be an issue, but in your case I would say it's pretty minor.

1. It looks good that Company X keeps hiring you back.
2. You may be able list your application process on your CV as some
   from of upskilling. I'm not familiar with your field, so I don't know
   what's a realistic amount of time for that to take, but even if it
   doesn't cover the whole gap, it will close it. If you can list new
   skills you learned or improved (research, self-direction, working to
   own initiative, specific software packages, etc.) that's even better.
3. I know it's not entirely in your own control, but if you can stay
   with Company X for eighteen months to two years that will do a lot
   to reduce interest in and concern over the earlier gaps in your CV.

Slightly off the point of your question, but just to explain my rational for point 3: I'm not saying don't job hunt if that's what you want to do, in the meantime. (Your post reads, to me, like you might be considering it.) A great chance might come along and they might not care about the gaps. But I would suggest staying with Company X while doing the job hunt if so, as it offers you more protection from further gaps and increases amount the experience you can list.

Also, I didn't pick 18 months - 2 years out of the air, though it might vary where you are; where I work, that's considered an employment sweet spot as you're experienced but not so much so that you start getting expensive. So it's a good early milestone for opening up job hunting opportunities. You can adjust that figure for your own locale, if you happen to know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just tell the truth. I think employers understand to at least some extent that the economy is tough right now, so gaps in employment aren't going to be viewed the same way they would if it was easy to walk out and get a job whenever you want, and the only reason why someone would be unemployed is if they're too lazy to work or if they're a problem employee. Make clear that the gaps are because a contract ended (or whatever the details were) and you were actively looking for work and just couldn't find anything, and not that you quit because you get bored easily and needed more time to develop your cocaine hobby.